# Sky from Equator at 8,000 years Before Present?

Tags: positional-astronomy, night-sky

The Stellarium software allows future views of the sky. I need an online resource (planetarium projector?) that shows pre-historical views, and from the Equator at 8,000 years before the present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can equally well just type in a negative year and Stellarium will navigate you into the corresponding year B.C. Don't forget that the year 0 didn't exist. 1 A.D. follows directly after 1 B.C.

A while ago I've confirmed that Stellarium is very accurate down to 1500 B.C. using a babylonian list of lunar occultations of stars. Thus, it should be reasonably accurate for the year 6000 B.C. as well.

Comment: Actually in Stellarium there is a year zero. 0 = 1 B.C., -1 = 2 B.C., -3 = 3 B.C. and so on. It's a very important distinction if you're trying to find something on a precise year like an eclipse.

Comment: @called2voyage: Yes, I had trouble with that as well. At first I thought Stellarium isn't that accurate at all, until I remembered that one year shift.